# Proper use of StartWith and Contains in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I want to remove prefixes from `StoreName` field in Linq `Linq to Entity` query.

I have following query which gets list of all prefixes in table

**Query1**

`var _prefix = context.Prefixes.Select(pre => pre.Prefix1);`

I want to use this result in **Query2**

**Query2**

```
var objRetailer = from stores in context.RetailerStoredtls
                  join ret in context.RetailerContactdtls
                  on stores.RetailerID equals ret.RetailerID
                  join retreg in context.RetailerRegDates
                  on stores.RetailerID equals retreg.RetailerRegDateId
                  where (stores.IsDeleted == null || stores.IsDeleted == false)
                                  && (stores.CreatedDate.Value.Year == iYear || stores.ModifiedDate.Value.Year == iYear)
                  && retreg.IsApproved== true
                  orderby stores.StoreName
                  select new
                      {
                           stores.StoreID,
                           Store = stores.StoreName,
                           Area = stores.StoreCity,
                           Zip = stores.StoreZip,
                           SellingCard = (storessellingcard.Contains(stores.RetailerID.Value) ? true : false)
                           StoreWithoutPrefix = stores.StoreName.StartsWith(<one of prefix retrieved from Query1> ? stores.StoreName : <stores.StoreName without prefix>
                                  };
```

Unfortunately we have `.StartWith()` that take only string parameter not result of **Query1**, if I go with `.Contains` it will not check for whether it starts with or not, it just check whether string is present there. What should I do to accomplish this task?

Thanks.

Comment: `_prefix.Any(p=>stores.StoreName.StartsWith(p))` would help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IndexOf`, but probably you have problems with case sensitivity. So add a parameter `CompareOptions.IgnoreCase`